# Multiple values to one key from 2 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, key, key-value

I'd like to combine 2 Arrays with array_combine. I want that the values of Array1 are my keys and the values of Array2 are my values.
The values come from a .yml-file which have componentgroup as Key and componentname as Value

```
   $yamlKeys = array();
    foreach ($yaml['components'] as $yamlComponent) {
        array_push($yamlKeys, $yamlComponent['cachet']['componentgroup']);
    }

    $yamlValues = array();
    foreach ($yaml['components'] as $yamlComponent) {
        array_push($yamlValues, $yamlComponent['cachet']['componentname']);
    }

    $yamlMap = array();
    $yamlMap = array_combine($yamlKeys, $yamlValues);

    echo("===== YAML MAP STARTS =====");
    var_dump($yamlMap);
    echo("===== YAML MAP ENDS =====");
```

My problem:
There can be keys with the same name.
In $yamlMap there will only be one value assigned (the last one). For example:

The Yaml-File looks like this:

```
FOO => BAR
Key1 => Value1
Key2 => Value2
FOO => BAZ
Key3 => Value3
```

My code does:

```
FOO => BAZ
Key1 => Value1
Key2 => Value2
Key3 => Value3
```

But I want it like that:

```
FOO => BAR, BAZ
Key1 => Value1
Key2 => Value2
Key3 => Value3
```

To be more precise: I want that "FOO" has more values (maybe an array of values) if there are more "FOO" keys.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: In your output, are you desiring a comma-separated string `'BAR, BAZ'` or an array containing two elements `['BAR', 'BAZ']`?  Do you expect `Value1` to be a string or an array containing one string?  Because of your accepted answer, I feel your question is Unclear.

Comment: I wrote "I want that "FOO" has more values (maybe an array of values) if there are more "FOO" keys." So yes, I want that the value is an array. Sorry for expressing myself unclear.

Comment: And do you want Key1 to point to a string or an array containing a single string?  Your expressed output is not clear.

Comment: if it's an array with string value1 then I agree, question is not clear. Also the accepted answer gives the exact same output with or without the if() part

Comment: It depends on the yaml file. The yaml file changes regularly in my case, so it could be, that Key1 can point to more values.

Comment: That is not the question. What is `Key1 => Value1` in your example. Is it a string or is it an array. example `["key1" => "value1"]` or `["key1" => ["value1"]]` It's a big difference. I personally would prefer option 2 as it's the same array structure all the time. But your question is option 1

Comment: @Juri_Wolkow please clarify your desired data type when a key holds a single value.  In other words,  we need to know if `Value1` of `Key1 => Value1`is a string or an array containing a string.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
$yamlMap = [];
foreach ($yaml['components'] as $yamlComponent) {
    $key = $yamlComponent['cachet']['componentgroup'];
    $value = $yamlComponent['cachet']['componentname'];
    // Lets initialize the key to be an array so that we may collect multiple values
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $yamlMap)) {
        $yamlMap[$key] = [];
    }
    // lets add the value to the map under the key
    $yamlMap[$key][] = $value;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/FtjQC

Comment: That didn't help at all. I corrected the syntax errors and got the same result (just the last value was assigned to the key, but not both)

Comment: @Juri_Wolkow try now, I flipped the params for `array_key_exists` and also fixed the syntax errors. It has been a while since i wrote PHP.

Comment: @Juri_Wolkow You have been tricked.  This answer does NOT deliver your desired output.  https://3v4l.org/SsqCX

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code does not work is because array_combine requires unique keys. So looping is the only way to get the values as you expect.

Here is one method where I loop the unique keys and use array_intersect(_key) to get the matching values.
If the count is more than one, I know the output subarray is supposed to be an array.
Else it's a single value in [0] item (beacuse of the array_values) and I just add that.

```
$yamlKeys = ["FOO","Key1","Key2","FOO","Key3"];
$yamlValues = ["BAR","Value1","Value2","BAZ","Value3"];

$yamlMap = [];
foreach(array_unique($yamlKeys) as $key => $ykey){
    $temp = array_values(array_intersect_key($yamlValues,array_intersect($yamlKeys, [$ykey])));
    if(count($temp)>1){
        $yamlMap[$ykey] = $temp;
    }else{
        $yamlMap[$ykey] = $temp[0];
    }
}

var_dump($yamlMap);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["FOO"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "BAR"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "BAZ"
  }
  ["Key1"]=>
  string(6) "Value1"
  ["Key2"]=>
  string(6) "Value2"
  ["Key3"]=>
  string(6) "Value3"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/hu2re

Since the "problem" is the FOO key I will explain what the code does to that key.

The code uses array_intersect to find the "FOO" keys and return:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "FOO"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "FOO"
}
```

Note the keys are matching your original array.
This is used in array_intersect_key which uses the keys numbers and grab the values from the values array with the matching keys.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "BAR"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "BAZ"
}
```

Then I use array_values to make the keys 0, 1.
$temp will now look like

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "BAR"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "BAZ"
}
```

Since the count is more than one the `if()` will be true and $temp-array is added to the key "FOO" of $yamlMap.
If it was only one item in the array only the single string would be added thus not multidimensional

Comment: This is exactly what I was seaching for. I'll need quite a time to understand it, but it works. Thank you very much, Andreas.

Comment: I will try and add some comments in the code to make it clearer

Comment: This is gold. Thank you Andreas!

Comment: @Andreas I was patient long enough. I voted Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is an even more direct approach:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vBDPU)) ([or this alternative/condensed version](https://3v4l.org/8T81q))

```
$yamlMap = [];
foreach ($yaml['components'] as $yamlComponent) {
    $key = $yamlComponent['cachet']['componentgroup'];
    $value = $yamlComponent['cachet']['componentname'];
    if (isset($yamlMap[$key])) {
        if (is_array($yamlMap[$key])) {
            $yamlMap[$key][] = $value;  // push to existing array
        } else {
            $yamlMap[$key] = [$yamlMap[$key], $value];  // convert string to array containing old string and new string
        }
    } else {
        $yamlMap[$key] = $value;  // save first occurrence as a string
    }
}

var_export($yamlMap);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'FOO' => 
  array (
    0 => 'BAR',
    1 => 'BAZ',
  ),
  'Key1' => 'Value1',
  'Key2' => 'Value2',
  'Key3' => 'Value3',
)
```

---

Initial solution:

Iterate through your data once to boil it down to a 2-dim array, then use `array_merge_recursive()`'s magic to convert it to your desired output.  `...` is the splat operator which tells `array_merge_recursive()` to treat `$result` like a series of 1-dim arrays rather than a 2-dim array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ITcLS))

```
foreach ($yaml as $components) {
    foreach ($components as $sets) {
        foreach ($sets as $cachet) {
            $result[] = [$cachet['componentgroup'] => $cachet['componentname']];
        }
    }
}

var_export(array_merge_recursive(...$result));
```

My solution starts from your untouched `$yaml` variable.

```
$yaml = [
    'components' => [
        [
            'cachet' => [
                'componentgroup' => 'FOO',
                'componentname' => 'BAR'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'cachet' => [
                'componentgroup' => 'Key1',
                'componentname' => 'Value1'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'cachet' => [
                'componentgroup' => 'Key2',
                'componentname' => 'Value2'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'cachet' => [
                'componentgroup' => 'FOO',
                'componentname' => 'BAZ'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'cachet' => [
                'componentgroup' => 'Key3',
                'componentname' => 'Value3'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Output:

```
array (
  'FOO' => 
  array (
    0 => 'BAR',
    1 => 'BAZ',
  ),
  'Key1' => 'Value1',
  'Key2' => 'Value2',
  'Key3' => 'Value3',
)
```

Comment: @Juri_Wolkow Do you understand mine?

Comment: Unfortunatley not. I should have mentioned that I'm actually not a PHP developer, but I have to do something right now in PHP. Nevertheless, I really appreciate your help, mick!

Comment: Your question is performing loops just to set up the keys array and the values array.  I have started from the beginning and changed your process to set up the use of `array_merge_recursive()` which naturally builds subarrays when keys are repeated.  My answer is very "function light" / efficient.